# Starting Flutter With Android Studio problems

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart

I want to run my hello world app on a device but when I run this app I catch errors in syncing .

I don't know how to fix it. I had done every work for starting app like downloading SDKs or PATH in System variables but it doesn't work at last step my flutter SDK is last version of it.

This is my flutter-tools/flutter.gradle file (default)

```
.
.
.
.
buildscript {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
   }
}

android {
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility 1.8
       targetCompatibility 1.8
   }
}

.
.
.
```

and this is the log

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find fragment.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/fragment/fragment/1.0.0/fragment-1.0.0.jar
   > Could not find lifecycle-runtime.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime/2.0.0/lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: and flutter doctor shows every thing is good

Answer (score 0):

your problem is gradle can't sync and download dependencies.
if you live in Iran use proxy or vpn
my suggestion is change your dns to  "178.22.122.100" and "185.51.200.2" (shecan.ir)

Comment: use another gradle version something like 3.6.2 may help

Comment: @mostafa_ksh78 yes in browser shows you 404. but if you use shecan.ir and set dns then gradle synced successfully. i test exact flutter gradle setup like yours and built okey

Comment: @mostafa_ksh78 yes, without problem

Comment: @mostafa_ksh78 after setting dns , disable your network interface and enable it again might help, after setting dns without other vpn and proxy check some google android developer like https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager in browser  might opens without problem

Comment: i can open this pages but same issuse

Comment: i cant sync android studio gradle but flutter cant connect to those links